# c# wpf Binding Command - access value of textbox from command

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I want to call a simple Command which adds values from my GUI into the database.

My Command:

```
private ICommand addSpeechCommand;
public ICommand AddSpeechCommand
{
  get
  {
    if (addSpeechCommand == null)
    {
      addSpeechCommand = new RelayCommand(param => AddSpeech());
    }
    return addSpeechCommand;
  }
}

public void AddSpeech()
{
  // TODO add 
OrganizerBL.InsertSpeech(new Speech(maxSpeechId, currentSpeech.Title, currentSpeech.Summary, currentSpeech.Start, currentSpeech.End, currentSpeech.TrackId, currentSpeech.SpeakerId, currentSpeech.ConferenceId, currentSpeech.Room));
  this.LoadSpeeches();
}
```

-- this commented out row shows how i dealt with it when a row of my datagrid was selected. but i want it to work without a currentSpeech

My XAML:

```
        <Label x:Name ="lblTitle" Content="Title"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTitle" Text="{Binding CurrentSpeech.Title, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2,144,0,0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

and other textboxes...

I really don't know how to access the values of the textboxes from the command to call my insertSpeech method...

Sorry for my english :)

UPDATE:
I'm getting a nullreference exception because my currentSpeech is null.
Is there a way to solve this without the currentSpeech?

Comment: where you bind AddSpeechCommand ? is it a button or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the NullReferenceException is probably because it's instanced in the property itself. When you cerate a binding, it's created to the property as it is at that stage. And you bind to the property when it's NULL. IT's actually created inside the property, but the Binding will never know that.

First of all, I would remove all logic from properties.
I would also implement the INotifyPropertyChanged to the class, and call the PropertyChanged in the property's "set". This means that the UI will know of any changes to the porperty.
Then I would create a depencency property for the property, if it's used in any Binding ot XAML.

Last, I would instance the command in the class's constructor.

Logic don't (in my book) belong to properties.

Answer (score 0):

How to do
1. Bind TextBox.Text to View model property
2. Use View model property in Command Handler.

---

In your case, You have binded `TextBox.Text` to `CurrentSpeech.Title`, but using `this.Title`.

In you command, change `this.Title` to `currentSpeech.Title`

Comment: hello, thanks.
that was an mistake of mine, but if i try to add the speech via my Add button i get an nullreference exception because the currentsSpeech is null ...

Comment: you should initialize currentSpeech in view model constructor, and then the properties of currentSpeech will be bound.